# Styling Bootstrap NavigationBar Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style some elements of a `bootstrap navbar`. However I couldn't figure out how to solve some `"graphical bugs"`.

First of all my list elements won't increase their height according to the `navbar`. When I hover over my elements it looks like this:

[image: hover/height bug].

What i want to achieve is, **that the hover(and therefore the whole element) takes 100% height of the navbar**.

Also I would like to **remove the background-color when a list elements get selected (= gets class "active")**.

This is how it looks at the moment:

[image: active bug]

However it would be nice to just set this `background-color` to `transparent`.

You can find a simplified example of my current setup here on **jsfiddle**:
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4858/)

I tried multiple things already which didn't gave the wished result. I'd like to provide some of my attempts but since I testes all directly in the browser console I can't really figure out what I have tried so far.

Maybe you have a good idea to solve my two tasks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i want to achieve is, that the hover(and therefore the whole
>   element) takes 100% height of the navbar.

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

> Also I would like to remove the background-color when a list elements
>   get selected (= gets class "active").

```
.nav > li > a:focus
{
  background: none;
}
```

> However it would be nice to just set this background-color to transparent.

```
.nav > li > a:focus
{
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the height attribute for your navbar.

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:#27586b;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:0;
    height:50px
}
```

Look http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4861/

so, if your height must be more then 50px, you should set it for `.navbar-custom` and for `.navbar-custom .navbar-nav` and set height = 100% for childs and use padding for vertical align.

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:#27586b;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:0;
    height:60px
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    height:60px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
    height:100%;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top:20px;
    color:#fff;
    height:100%;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4862/